# Influxdb - how to calculate sum of differences per second a the minute level

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I want to query the sum per minute from the result obtained from another query that calculates the difference between subsequent values.

```
select sum(ph1), sum(ph2), sum(ph2) from (select 
non_negative_difference(day_chan1) as ph1,
non_negative_difference(day_chan2) as ph2, 
non_negative_difference(day_chan3) as ph3 
from electricity) 
group by time(1m) tz('Europe/Dublin')
```

For example if I get the following from the suqbquery

```
time                 ph1 ph2 ph3
----                 --- --- ---
2017-04-02T14:40:38Z 0   0   2
2017-04-02T14:41:38Z 1   1   1
2017-04-02T14:41:39Z 0   0   2
2017-04-02T14:42:38Z 1   1   1
2017-04-02T14:42:39Z 0   1   2
```

I want to sum them up into

```
  time                 ph1 ph2 ph3
    ----                 --- --- ---
    2017-04-02T14:40:00Z 0   0   2
    2017-04-02T14:41:00Z 1   1   3
    2017-04-02T14:42:00Z 1   2   3
```

but what I get from the query is `aggregate function required inside the call to non_negative_difference` but if I do the sub query on its own, it returns the results

Comment: Did you try  to add group by time(1m) to inner query too? non_negative_difference() is an aggregate function.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking a long time for this and I finally found the solution:

```
select sum(ph1), sum(ph2), sum(ph2) from (select
```

This is right. Now we want to add an aggregate function inside the non_negative_difference call (as the error also indicates). I assume you want to sum everything.

```
non_negative_difference(sum(day_chan1)) as ph1,
non_negative_difference(sum(day_chan2)) as ph2, 
non_negative_difference(sum(day_chan3)) as ph3 
from electricity
```

Now if we don't add the following line the group by function of the inside query will also be 1m. We don't want this since if a value is missing the way influx calculates sum this will result in a very large differnce. So we group this subquery by the smallest interval you have (e.g. 1s)

```
group by time(1s))
```

Finally you can group the outer query by the interval you would like the values to be added together.

```
group by time(1m) tz('Europe/Dublin')
```